# Name error trying to open a file

Tags: python, file, syntax-error

I have made a quiz in Python and tried saving the score of the quiz along with the user's name in a .txt file, but I keep getting an error message, and I can't seem to work out why.

This is my code:

```
import random

import json

score = 0

turn = 1

turn = turn + 1

name = raw_input("what is your name?")

num_class = input("What class are you in? (1,2,3)")

print ("hello "+name+" have fun and good luck!")

for turn in range(10):


    randnum_1 = random.randint(1,10)
    randnum_2 = random.randint(1,10)
    operators = ["+", "-", "*"]
    operator_picked = operators[random.randint(0,2)]
    human_answer = raw_input("What is " + str(randnum_1) +" "+ operator_picked +" " + str(randnum_2) + "?")
    correct_answer = str((eval(str(randnum_1) + operator_picked + str(randnum_2))))


    if correct_answer == human_answer :
        score = score+1
        print ("Correct!")

    else:
        print ("Incorrect!" +"The correct answer is " + str(correct_answer))


print("\nYour score was " + str(score)+ "/10")


file_name = ("Class_" + str(num_class) + ".txt")

file = open(file_n,"r")

string = file.read()

file.close()

dict = {}

try:

    dict = json.loads(string)

except:

    pass

try:

    dict[name].append(score)

except:

    dict[name] = score
```

I keep getting this error message when running it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

line 47, in 
    string = file.read()
IOError: File not open for reading

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: `file_n` should be `file_name` I assume?

Comment: line `file = open(file_n,"r")` should read `file = open(file_name,"r")`

Comment: what would i need to change to create the file ? @Yaroslav Admin @ James Tobin

Comment: i noticed that before and changed that but i still get an error message

Comment: string = file.read()
IOError: File not open for reading

Comment: Are you sure, that line now reads as `file = open(file_name,"r")` exactly? Especially `"r"` part?

Comment: yes positive, i am not sure what to do, it says there is no file to open

Comment: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Class_2.txt'

Comment: this is the error message i get @yaroslav admin

Comment: And is it not clear what is the problem from the error message?

Comment: im not sure thats what im trying to work out

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't define `file_n`; you defined `file_name`.  You just need to change that line to `open(file_name, "r")`.

Comment: i realised that before but now i get this error message Traceback (most recent call last):
  
    string = file.read()
IOError: File not open for reading

Comment: There must be something else you left out.  That should work.

Comment: can u see anything that i might have missed